# Is there a way to synchronously get data from Firebase (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Swift iOS app with a Firebase backend. I'm trying to implement logic in my AppDelegate that retrieves User data before the initial view controller is presented, but as far as I'm aware, the only way to get data is the asynchronous `observeEventType` function. The problem is, much of the UI should be populated with user information, so I don't want my AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function completing before I retrieve the User information. Anyone know how to fix my problem?

**Edit:**

Would the idea of *sessions* fix my problem? Meaning, if a user logged in once, is their session active forever (unless they log out) in which case I'd be able to use the synchronous `authData` function?

Comment: If you use a synchronous approach then your whole app will appear to hang and this a bad user experience.  Better to show some indication to the user that data is being loaded, such as a UIActivityView, and then refresh the interface once the data is loaded

Comment: Thanks. I actually believe I was making an edit while you commented, would you be able to answer the question asked in the edit? @Paulw11

Comment: Please review the title of your question, it's not clear what you are asking. It  seems that you are asking more than one question here and you have other requirements in mind that you have not written.

Comment: Can you add your code on how you got the firebase data before the view loads!?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt post your code so it's not clear why didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is being used as there are a variety of other options.

For a simple example though, using a storyboard, create a login view controller as the entry point on the storyboard. Then in that view controller capture the users login email and password, authenticate and continue the flow through your app.

```
    ref.authUser(userName, password: password) { error, authData in

        if error != nil {
            print("No auth for you, two weeks")
        } else {
            print("authenticated as  \(authData.uid)")

            //now set up your app, populate user info etc.
            //  even calling back to the delegate would work.

        }
    }
```

Comment: But since `authData` is asynchronous, couldn't the UI load before the completion block finishes, causing many of the UI components initialized with nil data?

Comment: @rigdonmr Not exactly. You may need to have some component of the UI load before auth'ing the user. A login screen for example that captures the email and password and passes it to the ref.authUser block. Notice that we don't load any other UI elements until the block is executed. That way you are guaranteed to be working in an asynchronous fashion and not acting on data until Firebase returns the data.